# jakarta.xml.ws.spi.Provider: com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not a subtype

Tags: java, wsdl, jax-ws, java-11, microprofile

I'm trying to use JDK 11 in a Microservices using Microprofile, using another old project that generates code by WSDL, code generated by the JAX-WS RI, before was compiled with JDK 6.0 but I migrate to use JDK11. This is the POM of the old project that use WSDL with JDK 11

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>example-parent</artifactId>
        <version>${examplen-parent.version}</version>
    </parent>


    <artifactId>example-service</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.deploy.skip>true</maven.deploy.skip>

        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>example-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>example-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Separate dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <!--Test -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-inline</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <targetPath>META-INF</targetPath>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>jax-ws-catalog.xml</include>
                    <include>wsdl/**</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-site</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <wsdlFiles>
                                <wsdlFile>localhost:8081/Description/file.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                            </wsdlFiles>
                            <wsdlLocation>http://loclahost:8001/Description/file?wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                            <staleFile>${project.build.directory}/jaxws/stale/file.stale</staleFile>
                        </configuration>
                        <id>wsimport-generate-file</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxws-wsimport</sourceDestDir>
                    <xnocompile>true</xnocompile>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <extension>true</extension>
                    <catalog>${basedir}/src/jax-ws-catalog.xml</catalog>
                    <target>2.0</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I run the project, an inject the object of this old project, I'm getting this error

`jakarta.xml.ws.spi.Provider: com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not a subtype`

when I try to add these Dependencies

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

And also I add this one

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-ri</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

But then I got this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl cannot be cast to class jakarta.xml.ws.spi.Provider (com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl is in unnamed module of loader fish.payara.micro.boot.loader.ExplodedURLClassloader @5f2050f6; jakarta.xml.ws.spi.Provider is in unnamed module of loader org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader
```

Do you know if exist a ProviderImpl for JDK 11 (Jakarta) or how can I fix those problems

Answer (score 2):

had same issue and we solved with following adaption,

1. We used cxf-codegen-plugin(version 4.0.0) from org.apache.cxf. The version 4.0.0 generate all of the classes with jakarta instead of javax.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.apache.cxf}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-sources</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalJvmArgs>-Dorg.apache.cxf.Logger=info</additionalJvmArgs>
                    <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/cxf</sourceRoot>
                    <wsdlOptions>
                        <wsdlOption>
                            <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/dnb/yourwsdl.wsdl</wsdl>
                            <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/dnb/yourwsdl.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                        </wsdlOption>
                        <wsdlOption>
                            <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/crefo/yourwsdl.wsdl</wsdl>
                            <wsdlLocation>classpath:wsdl/crefo/yourwsdl.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                        </wsdlOption>
                    </wsdlOptions>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

2. Added following dependancies,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>${jaxws-rt.version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The dependancy jaxws-rt will help you to get rid of below error

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl cannot be cast to class jakarta.xml.ws.spi.Provider