# Unable to create Provider: class com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl cannot be cast to class javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I extracted a jar from a wsdl using the `wsimport` command (JDK 1.8).

Now, I'm trying to use that jar to execute a specific web service and it shows me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create Provider: class com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl cannot be cast to class javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider (com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl and javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:88)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
    at com.Service01.<init>(Service01.java:42)
    at com.kyc.MainApp.main(MainApp.java:45)
```

Here are the dependencies that I have used in the **pom.xml**:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.soap</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>rt</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>WSIMPOTJAR</groupId>
            <artifactId>WSIMPOTJAR</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5-b10</version>
        </dependency>
```

PS: I have tried these solutions below but neither one of them worked.

- [jakarta.xml.ws.spi.Provider: com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not a subtype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75223619/jakarta-xml-ws-spi-provider-com-sun-xml-ws-spi-providerimpl-not-a-subtype)
- [JDK 11; JAX-WS; Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54032558/jdk-11-jax-ws-provider-com-sun-xml-internal-ws-spi-providerimpl-not-found)
- [Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl despite the dependencies are defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49107375/getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-sun-xml-internal-ws-spi-providerim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The things that needs to be cleaned up in the pom.xml.

- Please remove all the `jakarta` dependencies as your code is using `javax` libraries.
- Found out that `jaxws-api` version `2.1` (to be specific, versions **<=** `2.3.x`) is not working with the `jaxws-rt` versions **>** `2.3.x` if you are running your code on JDK versions **>** `1.8`.

I have added scenarios on what issues I have encountered on **JDK 17**:

- `jaxws-api` <= **2.1** and `jaxws-rt` > **2.3.x**

This error will come:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Unable to create Provider: class com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl cannot be cast to class javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider (com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl and javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

- `jaxws-api` >= **2.2.x** and <= **2.3.x** and `jaxws-rt` > **2.3.x**

This error will come:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl
```

**Note:** I saw that this issue only happens when you are running the code on **JDK version > 1.8**.

Better run your code on **JDK 1.8** only. Then you will not get the above issues.

**Or**

Otherwise, you stay within **2.3.x** version for `jaxws-rt` for now if you want to run the code on higher JDKs.

---

**Solution:**

I have adjusted the **POM** to solve the issue (for **JDK >= 1.8**):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.xml.soap-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>WSIMPOTJAR</groupId>
        <artifactId>WSIMPOTJAR</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

This should work.

Comment: then it will show me this error in my code:
"The type javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required type com.sironkyc.ws.Service01"

Comment: @maryemneyli Let me check on that.

Comment: @maryemneyli Will you be able to update Service01 class if needed?

Comment: no, it is the main class of the jar that i created from the wsdl using the wsimport command

Comment: @maryemneyli I have updated my answer. See if this works now.

Comment: no it gives me this error now:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl

Comment: no actually, this error:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl
persists

Comment: @maryemneyli Error got hidden. You missed to add it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255719/discussion-between-maryem-neyli-and-anish-b).